# How to call a function from another class in kivymd using get_app_running

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm a beginner to kivy and i am trying to make this app which will allow the user to add a visit record, and I need to call the function add_task() in the DialogContent class, but it is in the Visit Screen class, and idk how to reference from there. I would be grateful for any help with this.

**my.py** file -

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
from datetime import datetime
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.effects import scroll
from kivymd.uix.list import ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem, ILeftBodyTouch
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivy.graphics import RoundedRectangle
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivymd.color_definitions import colors


class DialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.date_text.text = str(datetime.now().strftime('%A %d %B %Y'))


    def show_date_picker(self):
        date_dialog = MDDatePicker()
        date_dialog.bind(on_save=self.on_save)
        date_dialog.open()

    def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
        date = value.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')
        self.ids.date_text.text = str(date)

class ListRecord(ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem):
    def __init__(self, pk=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pk = pk

    def delete_item(self, the_list_item):
        self.parent.remove_widget(the_list_item)

class MD2Card(MDCard,RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior):
    md_bg_color = get_color_from_hex(colors['Cyan']['50'])

class VisitScreen(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(VisitScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.app = MDApp.get_running_app()

    task_list_dialog = None

    def show_task_dialog(self):
        if not self.task_list_dialog:
            self.task_list_dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Create Task",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=DialogContent(),
            )

        self.task_list_dialog.open()

    def close_dialog(self, *args):
        self.task_list_dialog.dismiss()

    def add_task(self, record, doc, task_date):
        print(record.text, doc.text, task_date)
        self.root.ids['container'].add_widget(
            ListRecord(text='[b]' + record.text + '[/b]', secondary_text=doc.text, tertiary_text=task_date))
        record.text = doc.text = ''

class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Cyan"

sm=ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(VisitScreen(name='visit'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

**main.kv**:

```
ScreenManager:
    VisitScreen:
<MD2Card>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 500
    spacing: 20
    orientation: "vertical"

<VisitScreen>:
    name:'visit'
    MD2Card:
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 12
        MDFloatLayout:
            MDLabel:
                id: record_label
                halign: 'center'
                markup: True
                text: "[size=48][b]Visiting History[/b][/size]"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.85}

            ScrollView:
                pos_hint: {'center_y': .5, 'center_x': .5}
                size_hint: .9, .8

                MDList:
                    id: container

            MDFloatingActionButton:
                icon: 'plus-thick'
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_light
                on_release: root.show_task_dialog()
                elevation_normal: 12
                pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':.05}


<DialogContent>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: "210dp"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 3

        MDTextField:
            id: record_text
            hint_text: "Add visit record..."
            pos_hint: {"center_y": .4}
            max_text_length: 50
            on_text_validate: (add_task(record_text, date_record.text), close_dialog())
        MDTextField:
            id: doc_text
            hint_text: "Add name of the consulting doctor and/or the hospital..."
            pos_hint: {"center_y": .6}
            max_text_length: 50
            on_text_validate: (add_task(doc_text, date_doc.text), close_dialog())

        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'calendar'
            on_release: root.show_date_picker()
            padding: '5dp'

    MDLabel:
        spacing: '10dp'
        id: date_text

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "SAVE"
            on_release: (add_task(record_text, doc_text, date_text.text), close_dialog())
        MDFlatButton:
            text: 'CANCEL'
            on_release: close_dialog()

<ListRecord>:
    id: the_list_item
    markup: True

    IconRightWidget:
        icon: 'trash-can-outline'
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        on_release:
            root.delete_item(the_list_item)
```

Comment: Did you try with `ids` ?

Comment: @ApuCoder no, could you show how i can do that

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `id` for `VisitScreen` in `kvlang` as,

```py
ScreenManager:
    VisitScreen:
        id: vs
```

Then you will be able to refer `VisitScreen` both in `python` and `kvlang`. Since this screen is there in the `root` widget, you may access it in `kvlang` using the reserved kw `app` (which is [equivalent](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords) to the static method `get_running_app` in python) as,

```py
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "SAVE"
            on_release: (app.root.ids.vs.add_task(record_text, doc_text, date_text.text), app.root.ids.vs.close_dialog())
```

Here `app.root` refers to your root widget `ScreenManager`.

You also need some correction in your method `add_task` of `VisitScreen`,
(it should be `self.ids['container']` not `self.root.ids['container']`).

Indeed there are other ways to accomplish this, but I found it as a simple one.